# How to compare 2 datasets using KD-Tree in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, kdtree, orb

BIG PICTURE: I am building a web-based AR application on JavaScript that uses openCV.js library to recognize some objects in space and project corresponding 3D models as AR elements. In general, it is so that first I extract feature points from the streaming video using ORB then I compare it to the database. If there is a match the object will be highlighted and if the user clicks on it the AR session will start and the corresponding 3D model will be shown.

PROBLEM: At the stage when I need to compare ORB featured with the database (which I have in .json file) I want to use KD-Tree to make it fast. But I cannot find any proper explanation of how to find matches between 2 sets of points.

Could you please give me any idea of how it can to be done?

Thank you very much.